# How to specify mapping templates in AWS SAM

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have an AWS lambda that acts on an events of the form:

```
{"id": "some-id", "stuff": "bla-bla-stuff-here" }
```

Now I want to attach an API Gateway endpoint with POSTs to an url of the form /stuff/{id} where the actual stuff would go in the body. So, on the integration request of the method there is a mapping template section which seems to allow for something like:

```
{
  "id": $input.params('id'),
  "stuff": $input.body
}
```

Now, how do I specify this template in the SAM file?

Comment: Since SAM is an abstraction of CloudFormation it supports CloudFormation's template features and resources. So, I think this post can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882203/describe-aws-api-gateway-body-mapping-templates-in-cloudformation

Answer (score 1):

SAM uses the Proxy integration to Lambda which I don't think works with request/response mapping. If it does, you would need to specify this in Swagger as the `DefinitionBody` property of the Serverless::Api as SAM doesn't currently have a property for adding Request/Response mapping and generating the Swagger for you. The easiest way to use Swagger is to inspect the generated CloudFormation template of your stack; copy-paste it into your SAM template under `DefinitionBody`; and then apply the necessary Swagger additions.